# How to format a 1D Time Series Array for a 1D CNN in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm running into a spot of trouble trying to train a 1D CNN for a 1D array of chemical reaction data. My data is (21000, 1) where each sample is labelled into one of three classes. I have reshaped my X_train as follows.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(21000, 1, 1)
```

Below is my 1st CNN layer.

```
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',
                        input_shape=(21000, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
```

The model seems to compile OK, but when I try to fit it, I get the following error.

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node sequential_16/conv1d_28/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](sequential_16/conv1d_28/conv1d/ExpandDims, sequential_16/conv1d_28/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [4,1,1,1], [1,2,1,64].
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use a kernel size of 2 with a sequence of length 1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D) of Conv1D layers,

Your 1D Convolution layer should respect this format : [image]

So instead of reshaping your array like :

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(21000, 1, 1)
```

Try this :

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(1, 21000, 1)
```

(But generally larger batch size is considered)

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(1, 21000, 1)
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu', input_shape =(21000, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
```

However, when looking to your error, as pointed by @Shubham you might have a problem before this layer, you are trying to transform a input [1,1,1,1]

> [image]

to an output [1,2,1,64]

You are downsizing too much your signal through the neural net

Comment: I have reshaped my data a bit to see if I can fix the issue, but now I am getting another error. `ValueError: Shapes (1, 1) and (1, 3) are incompatible`

Since each set of 7000 readings correspond to one sample, I have reshaped it into (3, 7000) whilst my labels are (3,1).

Comment: If your labels are (3,1) you might need 3 neurons as outputs of your net, however looking at your error i think you are outputing only 1 value (1 neuron)